# testing multiple HOC composed with recompose

Tags: reactjs, snapshot, recompose, react-test-renderer

I have a setup where I have a main container that is composed with multiple HOC using recompose.

The HOC in use are;

WithPageWrapper,
WithLoading,
WithError

Composed like this:

```
compose(
    withPageWrapper,
    withLoading,
    withError
)(MainContainer)
```

testing this logic is proving difficult. The project I am working on is using react-test-renderer and utilising the shallow render method.

So when testing a snapshot to make sure the error state is loading the snapshot only tests one level deep (due to the shallow render) and always returns:

```
<PageWrapper>
    <LoadingContainer>
    </LoadingContainer>
</PageWrapper>
```

Instead what i want to be seeing in the snapshot is:

```
<PageWrapper>
    <ErrorContainer>
    </ErrorContainer>
</PageWrapper>
```

as I would have expected the Loading HOC to simply render the main container as the loading prop is null or false.

Doing a full render instead of shallow render simply makes the snapshot near unreadable. Is there a way to use shallow render in react-test-renderer and test the composition of multiple HOC?

Answer (score 0):

All HOC functions in use can be mocked with some basic implementation like

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(Comp => props => (
  <div data-testid="FooHOC"><Comp ...props/></div>
));
```

that allows to efficiently assert results in a snapshot.

The effects of original HOC functions can be tested in dedicated tests.

Comment: So I still don't quite get this. Would I need to mock each HOC and then do the original shallow render to compare with the snapshot? I guess I am just not sure how mocking would help with the issue of using shallow render

Comment: The purpose of this is to do full render and get clean and predictable snapshot.